# Fluent ribbon split button list update items source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged, fluent-ribbon

Xaml:

```
<fluent:SplitButton Icon="24.png" ItemsSource="{Binding TestSource}">
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<List<TestModel>> TestSource { get; set; }
```

Update Method:

```
public void UpdateSource(ObservableCollection<List<TestModel>> newSource)
{
    TestSource = newSource;
    OnPropertyChanged("TestSource");
}
```

It works fine the first time, but when assigning the `TestSource` property to a new object, the list displays the old list, and don't get updated.

Comment: Include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem here, with the same split button control and all.

First, I recommend changing the declaration of `TestSource` to:

```
public ObservableCollection<TestModel> TestSource { get; set; }
```

Next, do not assign a new `ObjectCollection` to `TestSource`.

Instead, try this:

```
public void UpdateSource(ObservableCollection<TestModel> newSource)
{
    TestSource.Clear();
    TestSource.AddRange(newSource);
    OnPropertyChanged("TestSource");
}
```

It seems like the `ObjectCollection` changes are only triggered when manipulating it with its methods, not direct assignments.